# Using user_access() on Custom Node Type

Tags: users

How can I check if a user has access to create a new node of a custom node type?

In 'admin/people/permissions' I have an item named "Custom Type: Create new content" and it is enabled for authenticated users.

How can I use `user_access()` to verify against "Custom Type: Create new content"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
user_access($string, $account = NULL)
```

if a custom module you can say

```
 if (user_access('Custom Type: Create new content') {
    // do X
 }
```

this will check the current logged in user.  To check someone else

```
 $uid = //get if from somewhere;
 if (user_access('Custom Type: Create new content', $uid) {
    // do X
 }
```

When you create a node, Drupal checks this by default....so I assume that you are trying to check it somewhere else.   What function you would like to check it in,  I cannot predict, but any function, template file, preprocess, etc will do

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps I'm missing something, but noting that using exactly the text 'Custom Type: Create new content' does not work with `user_access`, at least not for me.

Instead, use the machine value of the permission. One way to get that is to look at the user permission page, and view the checkbox value for the permission.

For example, instead of this:

```
if (user_access('Basic page: Edit any content'))
```

use this

```
if (user_access('edit any page content'))
```

To [find the definition](https://api.drupal.org/comment/54043#comment-54043) of the machine name, look in the .module file of the module that defines the permission.

Answer (score 0):

user_access() function did not worked for me.
I used [node_access()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_access/7)

like this: node_access('create', 'custom_content_type', $user) and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Thought I'd share this.  (Druapl 6.x)

```
global $user;
$types = node_get_types();
foreach ($types as $type) 
{
    print '<pre>' . $type->name . '</pre>';
    if (node_access('create',$type->type,$user)) {
        $output = l(t('Add new '.$type->name), '/node/add/'.str_replace('_','-',$type->type));
        print $output;
    }
}
```